# SharePoint online dev/admin courses

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I am new to SharePoint online. Is there any good courses to pick up easily from admin/development purpose?.

I checked in LinkedIn learning and pluralsight and not able to find any development starting tutorials.

I am currently stuck on how to customize the emails and web parts and no idea where to find the code.

Comment: Both those platforms have lots of content around SharePoint development. What's wrong with those? https://app.pluralsight.com/search/?q=sharepoint+development

Comment: I am looking for the courses related to the SharePoint online.. I am not sure how to customize the SharePoint online through the GUI?. I am not able to find any courses related to the SharePoint online.. most of the courses related to on-prem sharepoint 2013 or 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dev content:

In Pluralsight search for "SharePoint Framework".

In Linkedin Learning search for "SharePoint Framework". (many here)

For demos, tutorials and documentation search for "sharepoint framework video site:docs.microsoft.com".

Do a general web search for "sharepoint framework video".

For admin, pretty much the same sources, but search for "office 365 administration".

Comment: Thank you for the update